# Print the alphabet letters that are not in the line c++

Tags: c++

So, what I'm trying to do is, open and read a file, but read only the first line. I have already done this part. I have to read each character on that line and then I need to print the alphabet letters that are not found in that line.

Let's say the line was: 
a b c D E f G H I j k L M n o

So, I will have to print the letters from p-z, because they are not in the line.

So, how will get the letters that are not in the line?!

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if(argc < 2){
    cerr << "Usage: pangram <filename>" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  ifstream infile(argv[1]);
  if (infile.good() == false){
    cerr << "Error opening file[" << argv[1] << "]" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  char ch;
  string line;
  int a[26] = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z};
  int brk = 0;

  while(infile.good()){
    if(brk == 0) {
      getline(infile, line);
      for(int i=0; i <= line[i]; i++){
        if(isalpha(line[i])) {
          if(line[i] == )
          cout << line[i] << endl;
        }

      }
    }
    brk ++;

    if(brk == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your attempted solution. We're not going to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: Use a `std::bitset`, one bit for each letter.  Iterate through the line, setting a bit for each letter.  After iterating go through the `bitset`, a false value indicates the letter doesn't exist.

Comment: Unrelated, since you're only reading one line, why do you have the while loop?  And shouldn't `i` go to `line.length()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of your solution. I'm intentionally using a stack allocation of 26 bools instead of bitset so it's easier to comprehend.

```
bool letter_was_seen[26] = {};  // initialize an array to hold 26 bools (A..Z) all to false
getline(infile, line);   // read a line into a string
size_t len = line.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    char ch = ::toupper(line[i]);  // convert to upper case
    if ((line[i] >= 'A') && (line[i] <= 'Z'))  // is it a valid letter A..Z ?
    {
        letter_was_seen[ch - 'A'] = true;  // mark it's place in the array as "seen"
    }
}

// now print the letters not seen within the line
for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
{
    int index = (int)(i - 'A');
    if (letter_was_seen[index] == false)
    {
        cout << i;  // print the letter not seen
    }
}
cout << endl; // print end of line to flush output
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution,

```
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  deque<char> allChars(26);
  iota(allChars.begin(), allChars.end(), 'a');

  char readString[] = "test xyz";

  for (char& c : readString) {
    allChars.erase(remove(allChars.begin(), allChars.end(), c),
                   allChars.end());
  }

  cout<<"Not removed: ";
  for (char& c : allChars) {
    cout<<c<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
```